# amazon redshift concurrent write results in inserted records, causing duplicates

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, duplicates, amazon-redshift

I have been trying to solve a problem where two concurrent updates on the same table are causing additional records to be created/inserted. Never experienced this in any other relational database, and nor would i. So i believe it's potential a quirk in redshifts architecture of distributing queries across multiple nodes, however cannot pinpoint or provide a real world example.

Before these two updates are run, i insert new data into the table. The insert contains a daily snapshot that fills out one day of data, most columns have empty values ready for the updates to populate them.

The updates are run concurrently, which are simple update sql's, updating their respective columns. If run individually i do not see additional records created and no duplication.

The updates operate across the entire table, over 200 million records, however the duplication occurs only in the records that where populated recently(the new data for that days period.

This is kind of a worry, as i would never assume an update would ever create new records, addition to the records created with the first insert.

What is even more bizzare is that the duplicate records hold different data.

I have checked to veryify that no other queries are running beyond the expected, by looking at redshifts query logs (stl_query).

Comment: "*the duplicate records hold different data*" - if they contain different values then how are they "duplicates"? Do you have a unique index on the columns in question? What is the definition of the table?

Comment: the are duplicates are on a composite primary key. redshift does not enforce keys, so duplicate can occur. What i am seeing is a duplicate record(according to the composite primary key.). however the other values differ. However the only sql being performed are two updates, and only when they are run concurrently. In any other typical database, this should not occur. so im questioning how this is possible on redshift.

Answer (score 1):

I find really hard to believe that an update created new values, are you really sure about this?
I've been trough complicate situations when It comes to concurrent transactions on the same table, so what I suggest is that you explicitly lock your table with:

```
lock table <table> in exclusive mode;
```

before you manipulate it (exclusive mode will allow reads but any write attempt will have to wait)

If you don't and 2 transactions try to update (Inserts are fine, BTW) the same table, you are most likely yo get a "ERROR:  1023 - DETAIL:  Serializable isolation violation on table" - or the behavior you are reporting

Comment: I should have thought about locking the table. I have since refactored the queries to perform synchronously. However i have this same issue occurring on another table. so i will try to lock the table before updating. Will let you know if it resolves this issue.

Comment: @theog How did you fix this issue? I'm dealing with a similar problem right now.